# Apache Flink two types of window, time and "count" windows

Tags: csv, stream, bigdata, apache-flink, sliding-window

I am trying to work with file as a stream with window.

Here is the code

```
object Prog {

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure()

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)

    val csvTableSource = CsvTableSource
      .builder
      .path("src/main/resources/data.stream")
      .field("numPers", Types.INT)
      .field("TIMESTAMP", Types.STRING)
      .fieldDelimiter(",")
      .ignoreFirstLine
      .ignoreParseErrors
      .commentPrefix("%")
      .build()

    tableEnv.registerTableSource("Data", csvTableSource)

    val table = tableEnv.scan("Data")
      .filter("numPers > 10")
      .select("*")

    val ds = tableEnv.toAppendStream(table, classOf[Row])

    ds.print()
    env.execute()
  }
}
```

The question is how to implement window here, for example, to show only values which are not older than one hour. 
Or the second window type, when I read say 50 last entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stream processing, windows are groups on which aggregates are computed.

Your use case seems to be different. If you'd like to keep the last `x` minutes or `y` last records, than this needs to be expressed differently in SQL.

Keeping the last `5` minutes would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM Data d WHERE d.tstamp >  (now() - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE)
```

So, this would be a filter on some kind of timestamp attribute.

Keeping the last 10 rows would be

```
SELECT * FROM Data d ORDER BY d.tstamp DESC LIMIT 10
```

*However*, none of these operations are yet supported by Flink (version 1.5) SQL or Table API.